# Permissions required to use custom performance counters

Tags: performancecounter

We are having some problems on installing our app on machines rather than upgrading. I am getting crashes in creating Performance Counts. Do an application have to be run as an Administrator for Performance Counters to work? And where are Performance Counters stored? I do not seem to be able to find them in the registry.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly (installing rather than upgrading?), also what kind of crash are you getting? What architecture are we talking about? OS? What instructions and performance counters are you looking at? I will assume Intel (IA-32).

The rough answer would be yes: depending on what performance counters you are accessing, and what you want to do with them, you might need to be running as an administrator.

The Intel processor architecture has a protection system that controls the access
of programs running on the processor to its resources (memory regions, registers, ports, etc.), implemented through privilege levels giving levels of access to these resources. The IA-32 architecture has four privilege levels (0 to 3). The highest privilege is at level zero, the lowest at level 3. Modern operating systems use level 0 for the operating system kernel, making level 0 also known as Kernel Mode in Linux (or Ring 0 in Windows OS). The level 3 is used for less critical programs. This is the level at which user space operates and where most application programs execute.

Depending on the configuration of both programmable and fixed counters, events can be accessed at the different privilege levels of user, kernel, or user+kernel. This is particularly useful to isolate measurements of a given piece of code from procedures run by the kernel.

In the case of performance counters, there are two available modes to access them: user
mode or kernel mode. Depending on the right of access, two instructions allow the reading of counters, RDPMC and RDMSR. The counters are configured by writing to the
corresponding MSR with the instruction WRMSR. This instruction can only be
executed at privilege level 0.

RDMSR can only be executed at privilege level 0, so users need an interface if they want
to read counters. RDPMC can be set to execute at any privilege level without the need
to enter the kernel (however setting it up requires privilege level 0). Note that this refers to the access to counters and not to what the counters are reading, which is set-up during configuration of the counters to read events that occur at user or kernel (or both) levels.

You can check the manuals for the architecture you are using, for Intel you can find them [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html)